# jQuery doesn't run effectively

Tags: jquery, button

I am working on a kind of script and i try to improve my script with jquery.Therefore , I added some code. However, this script doesn't run normally. For example,

```
<button class="yapistir"><div class="durum">Sabit</div>
<button class="yapistir"><div class="durum">Sabit Değil</div>
<button class="yapistir"><div class="durum">Sabit ama tam değil</div>
<button class="yapistir"><div class="durum">Sabit görünümlü fakat değil</div>
<button class="yapistir"><div class="durum">Sabit etc.</div>
```

When I click the button ,every durum class changing

My Code is below , what can i do for this situation.
King Regards.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.yapistir').click(function()
   {

          $('.durum').text("NewText");

   });
});
</script>
```

When I click the first button it will looks like :

```
<button class="yapistir"><div class="durum">NewText</div>
<button class="yapistir"><div class="durum">NewText</div>
<button class="yapistir"><div class="durum">NewText</div>
<button class="yapistir"><div class="durum">NewText</div>
<button class="yapistir"><div class="durum">NewText</div>
```

Comment: And what is it exactly, you want to do?

Comment: Every div should be unique , how can i say , if I click first button, first div should change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.yapistir').click(function () {
        $(this).next('.durum').text("NewText");
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mecMa/)

Answer (score 3):

You have to target only specific `.durum` element next to the clicked `.yapistir`:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7fWMv/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.yapistir').click(function()
   {

          $(this).next('.durum').text("NewText");

   });
});
```

And don't forget to close button tag.

Comment: Yeah it works but i want the div classes should change . For example 
<button class="yapistir">submit</button><div class="durum">sabit</div>

Comment: see updated answer... Next time ask it clearly in your question firstly by putting valid HTML...

Answer (score 1):

Edit: now that the question has changed:

```
$(this).next('div.durum').text('NewText');
```

<strike>Pass `this` as the context which means the the search for `.durum` will be limited to the current element.</strike>

```
$('.durum', this).text("NewText");
```

Comment: Are you closing the button tag? If so, where?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the next script: [Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/dGWbt/5/)

HTML:

```
<button class="yapistir"><div class="durum">Sabit</div></button>
<button class="yapistir"><div class="durum">Sabit Değil</div></button>
<button class="yapistir"><div class="durum">Sabit ama tam değil</div></button>
<button class="yapistir"><div class="durum">Sabit görünümlü fakat değil</div></button>
<button class="yapistir"><div class="durum">Sabit etc.</div></button>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.yapistir').click(function() {
        $('.durum', $(this)).text("NewText");
    });
});
```

With `$(this)` we are indicating that we want to modify the div with class `durum` contained in the actual button clicked.

With the next HTML you can get: [Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/dGWbt/11/)

```
<button class="yapistir">a</button><div class="durum">Sabit</div>
<button class="yapistir">b</button><div class="durum">Sabit Değil</div>
<button class="yapistir">c</button><div class="durum">Sabit ama tam değil</div>
<button class="yapistir">d</button><div class="durum">Sabit görünümlü fakat değil</div>
<button class="yapistir">e</button><div class="durum">Sabit etc.</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.yapistir').click(function() {
        $(this).next().text("NewText");
    });
});
```

Comment: No I think i don't explain correctly. div's text should change , At this example , button's text is changing